# Proof of $L^1(G)$ is commutative iff $G$ is abelian

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am reading the proof of  $L^1(G)$ is commutative iff $G$ is abelian in in Principles of Harmonic Analysis by Deitmar and Echterhoff(Theorem 1.6.4). I have some doubts in the steps. Let $f ,g \in L^1(G).$I know that we have the following identity 
$\int g(y^{-1})dy=\int g(y) \Delta (y^{-1})dy$ for $g \in L^1(G)$  wrt to the Haar measure in $G$. But how can we conclude using this that 
$\int f(xy)g(y^{-1})dy=\int g(y) \Delta (y^{-1})f(xy)dy$ ? Also How the expression $\int g(y)(\Delta (y^{-1})f(xy^{-1})-f(y^{-1}x))dy=0  \forall g$ implies $\Delta (y^{-1})f(xy^{-1})-f(y^{-1}x)=0$ for all $f \in C_c(G)$ why not to all $f \in L^1(G)$?

Finally we wil get $\Delta$ is unimodular. Then how this and $f(xy)=f(yx)$ for all $f \in C_c(G)$ implies $G$ is abelian?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, $F(y)=f(xy)g(y^{-1})$ $\Rightarrow $ $F(y^{-1})=f(xy^{-1})g(y)$ and use the identity that you mentioned to conclude.

For the second question, consider $g(y)=\overline{\Delta(y^{-1})(f(xy^{-1})-f(y^{-1}x)} $, by that you can conclude the desired equality for all $f\in C_{c}(G)$  (since $\Delta$ is continuous and nowhere-vanishing) but not for all $f\in L^{1}(G)$ because $\|f\|_{L^{p}} = 0$ doesn't imply that $f=0$.

For the last question , if $xy \neq yx$ , by Urysohn's lemma, $\exists f\in C_{c}(G) $ such that $f(xy)=1$ and $f(yx)=0$.